# Regex Iframe tags

Tags: php, regex, iframe

How can I "cut out" iframe tags in a string using regex so I can place them somewhere else on my page.

I got a page which shows an image at the top of an article, but when I add a video using my cms, I want that embedded video to be placed on the position of that image instead.

How can I look for those tags in a string and make them part of an array?

For example:

String:

```
This is the article title
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/23r23ffwe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
This is the article text
```

Should be usuable like:

```
$array[0] (title)
$array[1] (iframe)
$array[2] (text)
```

How can I select these tags? I can't find a clear answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: Use a proper DOM parser like e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php, that's what they're designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('@(.*)(<iframe(?:.*?)</iframe>)(.*)@gs', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Then see `$matches` array. Or [View regex in online debugger](https://regex101.com/r/11BrH5/1)

Comment: Thanks! What I needed